# Sum of values in selected datasets - charts.js line chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, dom-events, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm trying to show the sum of values on the chart in the title. i.e. 
Daily Report **(Total: 6242.12)**

I'd like to update this number whenever any dataset is excluded in the chart by clicking on the dataset icons on the top section of the canvas.

At the moment I have a few buttons outside the chart that updates the data in the chart and shows the sum of values, but of course it doesn't work when a user clicks a certain dataset to include/exclude from the line chart.

```
// Initializing Charts
    myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myDummyChart"), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: dates,
            datasets: [{
                data: dummyData1,
                label: "dummyData1",
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                fill: false
            },{
                data: dummyData2,
                label: "dummyData2",
                borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
                fill: false
            },{
                data: dummyData3,
                label: "dummyData3",
                borderColor: "#3cba9f",
                fill: false
            },{
                data: dummyData4,
                label: "dummyData4",
                borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
                fill: false
            },{
                data: dummyData5,
                label: "dummyData5",
                borderColor: "#c45850",
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            events: ['click'],
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: '30-Day Report (Total ' + total.toFixed(2) + ')'
            },
            responsive : false
        }
    });
```

Any leads?